Best way to manage an ungrounded circuit
Newish home owner here. Our house is from 1959 and some of the electrical is not super inspiring. One of the older circuits is ungrounded with cloth sheath but rubber/plastic insulated (I believe its Dutrax).
In outlets that I've found that are ungrounded, I've replaced the receptacles with GFCIs. However, I'm wondering if the best option would be to replace the entire breaker with a GFCI breaker. The breaker is a 2 pole 15A. How complicated would this be for me to do myself? I have >2000 hours working as an electricians apprentice over a decade ago. I remember a lot of it, but I never did much work in the panel. It seems like it would be pretty straightforward to just do a 1-to-1 swap of the breaker
Many of these receptacles boxes are small, barely fitting the GFCIs. I've been covering the terminals with some electrical tape to make sure that they don't accidentally contact the steel boxes. Is this acceptable?

Post a picture of your breaker panel, including the breakers and also a view of any labels (often on the inside of the door). 1959 is pretty early for breakers; some brands that were in use then had good designs and have survived until today (meaning you can still buy effective GFCI breakers for them), some were garbage and have been discontinued.

@nobody In my neighborhood of 1950s homes, a very high percentage have had full panel replacements over the years but with the old wiring mostly still in place. So it is very likely that they have a new-enough panel that GFCI breakers are an option despite having old ungrounded circuits. In my area at least, a panel replacement/heavy-up does not trigger the need to AFCI and GFCI everything or replace old circuits.

I've never seen an ungrounded circuit! Only ungrounded low power connections to a grounded circuit. Replace all rubber/cloth/ancient plastic with new wiring.

@JeremyBoden There are plenty of ungrounded circuits out there. Already by the mid-1950s I think most new construction had grounds, but not all, and there are plenty of older houses with original circuits as well. Full wiring replacement gets rather expensive if you have to open up walls to do it. Even more so if the walls are also older and not drywall.

@JeremyBoden Japan didn't require grounded sockets be regularly installed until 2005. For the few appliances that required ground, like washing machines, they gave you, at best, a spade connector and screw.

The panel is newer, and the breakers are "regular", square D style. My hunch is this is a MWBC.


replace the entire breaker with a GFCI breaker

That is certainly a functional solution. A double-pole GFCI breaker is not cheap - you can typically get several GFCI receptacles for the price of one GFCI breaker. Remember also that you only need to replace the first receptacle in each chain with a GFCI receptacle to get full protection, though you are required (cough cough) to label all the following receptacles to indicate that they are GFCI protected (good) and no ground (if you replace them with 3-prong receptacles in order to allow use of 3-prong plugs, which you can do in this situation).
The one exception where it makes senses with an MWBC. If you have an MWBC then, depending on the wiring scheme, you may find that extra work is needed to properly split up the circuit so that you can install GFCI receptacles. In that case, GFCI breaker really makes a lot of sense.
If you have a main breaker or a disconnect before the relevant panel in order to safely cut power to the panel you are working on then replacing the breaker should be very easy to do. Electricians routinely install or replace breakers with the panel live, but turning it off first is not an unreasonable thing to do and could help avoid problems, particularly if the panel box is crowded.

barely fitting the GFCI's. I've been covering the terminals with some electrical tape to make sure that they don't accidentally contact the steel boxes

Yes, that's perfectly fine. As long as they really do fit. I have some boxes in my 1950s home which couldn't even fit a modern regular receptacle, let alone a GFCI receptacle, and I replaced the boxes. Of course, replacing boxes is easy in an unfinished basement and not quite as easy in other rooms.
But wait, steel boxes? Before jumping to GFCI everywhere, check to make sure the boxes aren't grounded already. I thought I would need to use GFCI receptacles to add grounded receptacles in several locations in my 1950s house and, so far at least, every single one of them turned out to have a good ground. But in some cases that was via a ground wire connected to the outside back of the box instead of being brought inside. Probably violated code, and I fixed them up to match the normal configuration, but the important thing is that the ground wire was there and working properly. (I haven't had to put in a GFCI receptacle in lieu of ground yet, though I have had to do plenty of other things, like fix hot/neutral reverses and switched neutrals and other craziness.)

A nice easy test for good ground is reading ~120v between hot and the box.  Assuming nothing funny done with neutral.

Sorry for the late reply. There is actually no ground (no voltage between hot and the box). Some of the boxes I've opened with grounds did just have the ground tied to the inside of the box so that's a valid question. The box does fit a GFCI, but the clearance is not super great hence I added some tape to the terminal. The circuit has some lighting and outlets on it. Of the outlets I've opened on the circuit (just 2), none of them had a load side, just a line coming in. Hence, they all needed to be GFCIs. My hunch is that this is a MWBC, maybe with junction boxes (?).


It seems like it would be pretty straightforward to just do a 1-to-1 swap of the breaker

For a regular breaker, the neutral goes straight to the neutral bar, with a GFCI, the neutral passes through the breaker and the current is monitored, along with the current in the hot conductor(s) to determine the leakage. There are a few things to be aware of as a result of this.

You may need to extend the wire to make it reach.
If circuits are wired in single wires, it may be difficult to identify which conductor is the correct neutral for the circuit in question.
Sometimes installers take shortcuts borrowing the neutral from one circuit to feed equipment on another, or abusing a ground as a neutral or vice versa.
There may be latent ground to neutral faults which will become apparent when a GFCI is added.

So adding GFCI protection can easily turn into a fault-finding exercise.

This is good to know. It could be difficult to determine the neutral. The tricky thing is the outlets I've found without grounds had no load going out, just a line in, so they can't protect anything downstream of them. In addition, there is a good amount of lighting on this circuit too, some of which should have a ground. I think the only way to protect this would be at the breaker?
